# php if else not working in this scenario

Tags: php, html, forms

I wrote a code such that if I fill all fields of form and I submit then I should get "Ok"

and if I left the form blank then I should get "Please fill all fields".

I am not getting any errors so I am confused how to proceed .

```
<?php

   if(isset($_POST['submit_text']) && isset($_POST['find_word']) && isset($_POST['replaced_word'])){
       $sub_text = $_POST['submit_text'];
       $fin_text = $_POST['find_word'];
       $rep_text = $_POST['replace_word'];
       if(!empty($sub_text )&& !empty($fin_text) && !empty($rep_text)){
           echo "Ok.";
       }else{
           echo "Please fill all fields.";
       }
   }
?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="index.php" method="post" >
   <p>
      Submit Text<br/>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="40" type="text" id="submit_text" name="submit_text" ></textarea>
   </p>
   <p>
      Find<br/>
      <input id="find_word" name="find_word" type="text"  />
   </p>
   <p>
      Replace<br/>
      <input id="replace_word" name="replace_word" type="text" />
   </p>
   <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

For any query please comment below.

Comment: Instead of doing it all twice, just do `!empty()` on the outer if, and use else on that instead. As long as the form is submitted, the first if will always be true.

Comment: And `replaced_word` != `replace_word`

Comment: I realized my mistake. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missed few characters here

```
isset($_POST['replaced_word'])
```

you have to use same name you use in input field.like this

```
isset($_POST['replace_word'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first "if" needs an "else", I think it would trigger that in your scenario.

I generally try separating these, and do not put them into one large IF..
for example, I would do an if isset and else on each one separately, converting to a different variable accordingly before doing the rest of the logic.

Answer (score 1):

In the first if, you wrote "replaced_word", but the name of the input tag is "replace_word" without the "d". So $_POST['replaced_word'] is never set so that's why it's not working.